# Adding a symbol (or group symbols) to each Vector element on Rust

Tags: string, rust, vector, environment-variables

What is my problem?
I get the current directory with the help

```rust
let dir: String = env::current_dir().unwrap().display().to_string();
```

Next, I need to make `Vec<String>` out of this line, for example, so that from a string type `"home/user/project"` to get `vec!["home/", "user/", "project"] as String`.

I tried a couple of options, but there are constantly errors of types and much more, but one of my options, which, in my opinion, was closest to

```rust
let dir_split: Vec<(there should be a type of String, but it turns out ())> = dir.split('/').map(|s| s.to_string().push('/')).collect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `str::split` use `str::split_inclusive` which would mean you don’t need to manually `push`, which is causing you issues.

When you use `map`, you are mapping each value to the the value returned by the expression. In this case, this would be `String::push`, which is returns `()`.

```rust
let var: Vec<_> = dir.split_inclusive('/')
    .map(String::from)
    .collect();
```

Comment: You shouldn't be splitting paths manually, you should use `Path` methods like [`components()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.components).

Comment: While I do agree that splitting a path manually is generally not what should be done, and such a task is better handled by functions of `Path` or `PathBuf`, the question asked was "How do I go from <input> to <output>", which I answered.